# Display a float in scientific notation

Tags: objective-c, formatting, floating-point

The following yields 6000:

```
firstLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",(6*pow(10,3))];
```

How can this be made to display the number in scientific notation, like `6 x 10^3` or `6e3`?

Answer (score 4):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

in short you want %e.

Comment: Probably `%e`, actually, since he wants lower-case `e`.

Comment: ah, yes, finger still on shift from '%' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
NSString *formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:someNSNumber];
```

And yes, release your formatter.